# New user gets duplicated to all virtual hosts

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

Every time I add an user, it gets duplicated to all virtual hosts. I've been facing this issue for a while and found a way to solve it, see [this post](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/5157/index.html), it says I have to configure a separate database to each virtual host.

What I can't understand is why Ejabberd has this default behavior in first place, what is the benefit to do so?

And what about [mod_mam](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration#mod-mam)? How do I configure it to store each message into its own database?

[My ejabberd.yml](https://gist.github.com/VitorCioletti/6006f9f3775dcb5c90949565fb6cde22) (mod_mam configuration at line 113)

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

> and found a way to solve it

Since recent ejabberd versions, you can use the new SQL schema, and configure ejabberd to use it, see in

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#relational-databases

> What I can't understand is why Ejabberd has this default behavior in
>   first place, what is the benefit to do so?

One possibility is the saved space for very big servers. Of course, when having many small servers, it's preferable to use one single database.

> And what about mod_mam? How do I configure it to store each message
>   into its own database?

It's the same with this module than with the other ones: if you configure it to use 'sql' storage, and you configured ejabberd to use a certain database for host "example.net", and a different one for "example.com"..., then mod_mam will use the correct SQL database to store the MAM messages depending on the user that wants to store them.

Se the first and second example configs in section https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#virtual-hosting

On the other hand, if you use the new SQL schema, you only define one database, so those doubts do not appear.

[also asked in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2752 ]